# Move + rename content items to a different folder in Plone

Tags: plone

We'd like to move and rename objects to a different folder in Plone in a single script operation.

- Is there a single API'sh call which would accomplish this?
- Alternatively: should one call cut + paste + manage_renameObjects() or is there a simpler chain of calls?

Comment: simpler than cut + paste + manage_renameObjects()? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should cut + paste + `manage_renameObjects()`. That's the only API you have available. :-)

I often use a helper method for the job:

```
from Acquisition import aq_parent, aq_inner

def move(id_=None, ob=None, parent=None, dest=None, newid=None):
    # Either provide id and parent, or ob.
    if id_ is None:
        id_ = ob.getId()
    if parent is None:
        parent =  aq_parent(aq_inner(ob))
    clipboard = parent.manage_cutObjects([id_])
    result = dest.manage_pasteObjects(clipboard)
    if newid is not None:
        dest.manage_renameObject(result['new_id'], newid)
```

Answer (score 2):

Martijns answer was right at the time, but now Plone has an API which provides the required methods:

http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.api/docs/content.html#move-content